# VBA Excel find date period in range and do calculations within

Tags: excel, vba

I am performing a VB function to sort out cumulative amount within a specified period with different categories. The objective is for personnel account expenses.

For example, I have in a sheet "tmp" in column A some dates, in column B a category (eg. Salary, Transport ...) and in column C the values.

I want to define a function and I have tried to set:

```
Function Cumulatif(Categorie As String, Debut As Date, Fin As Date) As Double
    ' Do the sum of a category between a starting and ending date specified 
    Dim Operations As Variant
    Dim SpecificSum As Double
    Dim i As Integer
    Operations = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("tmp").Range("A1:C3")
    For Each Row In Operations.Rows
        SpecificSum = 0
    Next
    Cumulatif = SpecificSum
End Function
```

But I don't really know how to get the values from another sheet and do the loop in the range to set this sum. Can somebody help me on this?

Comment: This way the function returns a #VALUE error ! I don't get why ?

Comment: If you want `Operations` to be assigned as a Range object, then you need to use `Set`.  If you really meant it to be a variant 2-D array (which you get by not using set), then that's not going to have a `.Rows` collection...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The assigment to operations needs to be an object assignment, meaning: use Set (not Let/default).

   Set Operations = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("tmp").Range("A1:C3)
2. You can get the values from the other sheet (assuming you mean "tmp") as follows

   ```
   SpecificSum = SpecificSum + Row.Cells(1, 1)
   ```

I think you'd be better off having the function take an additional range parameter and supplying Sheet1!A as an argument; this way Excel will know when it needs to recalculate.

```
Function Cumulatif(Categorie As String, Debut As Date, Fin As Date, Operations As Range) As Double
    ' Do the sum of a category between a starting and ending date specified
    'Dim Operations As Variant
    Dim SpecificSum As Double
    Dim i As Integer
    'Set Operations = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:C3")
    For Each Row In Operations.Rows
        SpecificSum = SpecificSum + Row.Cells(1, 1)
    Next
    Cumulatif = SpecificSum
End Function
```

And call Cumulatif using such a formula:

```
=Cumulatif("hello9","10/1/2010", "10/31/2010",Sheet1!A2:A3)
```